# Computing Square Roots

Tags: matlab

[image]

Here is my code:

```
a = 5;
x0 = 0.5;
tol = 1e-15;
MAX_ITER = 1000;
x(1) = x0;
for n = 1:MAX_ITER
  x(n+1) = x(n) - (1./2).*(x.^3).*(a-(1./(x.^3)));
  if abs(x(n+1)-x(n)) < tol*abs(x(n+1))
    break;
  end
end

x'
```

I do not know what to do because I am just getting errors. The function I choose is `(1/x^2)-a` which still gives division in the denominator which might be wrong.

Comment: `(x.^3)` and `(x.^3)` are both vectors after the first iteration and you're trying to assign them to a single index, `x(n+1)`, hence the `In an assignment  A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be the same` error. Given the equation, what do you think you should change to get rid of the error?

Comment: Do you think then I chose the wrong function?

Comment: Yes, but that's not what is causing the error.

Comment: Yeah I understand that the error isn't about the function but how I expressed it. Do you know a better function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working script, based on the equation shown in the excerpt you posted:

```
% Define the parameters...
a = 5;
x0 = 0.5;
iter = 1000;
tol = 1e-15;

% Create a vector for storing the iteration results...
x = NaN(iter,1);
x(1) = x0;

% Perform the computation...
for n = 2:iter
    x_prev = x(n-1);
    x_curr = 0.5 * (x_prev + (a / x_prev));

    x(n) = x_curr;

    if abs(x_curr-x_prev) < tol*abs(x_curr)
        break;
    end
end

% Clear the preallocated vector from unused slots...
x(isnan(x)) = [];

% Output the result...
x = [x repmat(sqrt(5),numel(x),1)]
```

The final output is:

```
x =
                       0.5          2.23606797749979
                      5.25          2.23606797749979
          3.10119047619048          2.23606797749979
          2.35673727264418          2.23606797749979
          2.23915722273719          2.23606797749979
          2.23607010853285          2.23606797749979
          2.23606797750081          2.23606797749979
          2.23606797749979          2.23606797749979
          2.23606797749979          2.23606797749979
```

The problem is that you are confusing scalar values extracted through indexing on a vector and element-wise operations performed on the vector itself. Your solution is half way between a vectorized solution and an iterative solution.

Comment: Thank you for help with the code and explaining where I was going wrong in the answer.